# Почему функция не видит переменную в global?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
url = 'https://yandex.ru'
req = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
tag = bs.find('tbody').text
tag_index = tag[16:28]
def convert():
    global vvod
    vvod = e1.get()
convert()
e1 = Entry(w, width=25, textvariable=vvod, state='readonly')
e1.grid(column=2, row=0)
```

```
    File "C:\Users\XXX\PycharmProjects\untitled5\main.py", line 23, in <module>
        convert()
      File "C:\Users\XXX\PycharmProjects\untitled5\main.py", line 22, in convert vvod = e1.get()
    NameError: name 'e1' is not defined
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, буду очень благодарен

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit] под вопросом)

Comment: ошибка происходить в функции `convert`, содержимое которой мы не знаем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вызываете функцию `convert()` до того, как заполнили переменную `e1`, значит этой переменной не существует. Даже если переставить `convert()` после создания `e1`, из `e1` будет приходить пустая строка, т.к. сразу после создания текстового поля там пусто. Нужно считывать строку после какого-то действия пользователя, например после нажатия на кнопку, пример:

```
def convert():
    global vvod
    vvod = e1.get()
    print(vvod)

e1 = Entry(w, width=25)
e1.grid(column=2, row=0)
Button(w, text="Нажми меня", command=convert).grid()
```

Убрал `readonly` ("только для чтения", т.е. нельзя ничего вписать), т.к. бессмысленно считывать что-то из текстового поля, в которое нельзя ничего вписать.

Также убрал передачу `textvariable` в `Entry`, т.к. туда нужно передавать объект класса `StringVar`, а вы, как я понимаю, туда пытаетесь передать текстовую переменную из функции `convert`.

Answer (score 1):

попробуй создать пустую переменную вне функции vvod = ''

Comment: Зачем? И vvod в данном случае это переменная, а не функция

Comment: Я не говорил,что vvod - функция. Я в конце привел пример,забыл выделить это,тк на сайте только зарегестрировался,извините

Answer (score 1):

вы переменной `vvod` присваиваете значение `e1.get`, но вы ещё не создали `e1`, а для создания `e1`вы используете `vvod` поэтому функция `convert` бессмысленна.

```
vvod = ""
e1 = Entry(w, width=25, textvariable=vvod, state='readonly')
e1.grid(column=2, row=0)
```